# JavaFx : Is there difference between String and StringProperty in Model Classes?

Tags: design-patterns, mvc, javafx

I'm trying to follow MVC concepts when i develop my application ,but I'm confused between Using `String` or `StringProperty` in Model classes.

Example one :

```
public class User{

    String name;
    String password;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User(String name, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
    }
```

Example Two:

```
public class User{

    StringProperty name;
    StringProperty password ;

    public StringProperty getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(StringProperty name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public StringProperty getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(StringProperty password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User(StringProperty name, StringProperty password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
    }
```

I'm using example one ,Is there difference between these models or are they the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JavaFX property is an observable container that facilitates *data binding*: The view can be connected with properties in the view model, so that it automatically updates when the model is changed.

So – use property fields if you want data binding, use ordinary strings when you don't need data binding.

In any case, the property should be bound to a specific model object. You should see a property as a special kind of variable, not as an ordinary object. So passing a property in a setter or in a constructor is highly unusual. Instead, your getters, setters and constructors would usually operate on the data stored within a property. This way, your property-based classes can also be used as Java Beans.

E.g. code using a property might look like this:

```java
public class User{
    private StringProperty nameProperty = new StringProperty();

    public final String getName() {
        return nameProperty.get();
    }

    public final void setName(String name) {
        nameProperty.set(name);
    }

    // expose the property for data binding
    // – possibly use a read-only interface
    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return nameProperty;
    }

    public User(String name) {
        nameProperty.set(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: So for example when I make a change by using `setName(String name)` the value in view will change automatically or should i use some bindings methods ?

Comment: @XlintXms If the view is set up to be bound to the StringProperty, then setting the name on the model object will update the view automatically. All of the JavaFX widgets support this data binding.

Answer (score 0):

One difference that should be noted is `JavaFX` properties are not `Serializable`. See @jewelsea answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791566/notserializableexception-on-simplelistproperty).